# MySQL Trigger can't get to set the variable when updating a table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to get the sum of table Product_sizes 'stock' column and put it in a variable. After that, I intend to update the Products table 'stock' column. But when I try to run the query, it shows a syntax error.

Here's the 'Products' table

[image]

Here's the 'Product_sizes' table

[image]

And here's my SQL query

```
CREATE TRIGGER product_sizes_stock_sum BEFORE UPDATE on product_sizes
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(stock) INTO @stocksum FROM product_sizes WHERE product_id = OLD.product_id;
    UPDATE products SET stock = @stocksum where id = OLD.product_id;
END
```

Here's the error message

[image]

I am following the Laravel convention of naming tables.

I'm really confused right now. Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).  this is also true for table definitions, because they are not defined as an image.   Also the full error message is missing.

Comment: Read about the `trigger_event` when creating a trigger (here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) Especially the difference between `UPDATE` and `INSERT` seems to be the problem here.  The same for `trigger_time`, should it be `BEFORE` or `AFTER` ?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question including the error message.I tried using BEFORE and AFTER on trigger_time but still not working.  I have already read that page but I'm still lost.

Comment: When defining a TRIGGER, you have to use a different [DELIMITER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html), (the same way as with creating stored procedures)

Comment: Ohhhh thank you very much Luuk. It is now working. An error "#1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)" showed but I fixed it through some Googling. Guess I need to study more. Thank you very much again!